# Multiple cookies added not merged into single HTTP header in Spring Webflux

Tags: java, spring, cookies, spring-webflux

I'm trying to send a request using Spring Webflux's WebClient including multiple cookies. My code looks like this:

```java
Mono<Void> loginCall = webClient.post()
                           .uri("/Sites/Login")
                           .cookie("key1", "value1")
                           .cookie("key2", "value2")
                           .cookie("key3", "value3")
                           .exchange()
                           .flatMap(clientResponse -> clientResponse.bodyToMono(Void.class));
```

What I receive on my endpoint looks like this (note the multiple cookie headers):

```
$ nc -l -p 8989
POST /Sites/Login HTTP/1.1
user-agent: ReactorNetty/0.8.11.RELEASE
host: localhost:8989
accept: */*
transfer-encoding: chunked
cookie: key1=value1
cookie: key2=value2
cookie: key3=value3
```

My expectation is to receive a HTTP request like this (a single cookie header):

```
cookie: key1=value1; key2=value2; key3=value3
```

I'm using Spring Boot 2.1.8.

I've tried numerous ways but everything I tried results in multiple cookie headers. The HTTP specification is quite clear about the fact that multiple cookie headers **must not be used** (and my web server receiving this request doesn't like it either).

How do I add multiple cookies to a WebClient request so that they are merged into a single HTTP header? (Yes, I can start setting the header manually and merge the cookies, but this somehow feels wrong)

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem, the only way I found was to produce the 'Cookie' header manually like this (Groovy language):

```
UserInfo retrieveUserInfo(List<Cookie> cookies) {
    String cookieHeader = cookies.collect { "${it.name}=${it.value}" }.join('; ')
    return webClient
            .get()
            .uri('your API path here')
            .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
            .header(HttpHeaders.COOKIE, cookieHeader)
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(UserInfo.class)
            .block()
}
```